# How to select parent child records with condition in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I need to search title `'%p%'`. if i check title ,parent tile and status as parent and child level. if the searched title parent visible is true then show the child Title.

```
CREATE TABLE CTE(
        Title VARCHAR(20),
        ParentTitle VARCHAR(20),
        visible VARCHAR(20),    
        showwhenvisiblefalse VARCHAR(20)
    ) 

INSERT INTO CTE
VALUES
('p1', 'Home', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'),
('p1.1', 'p1', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'),
('p1.2', 'p1', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'),    
('p1.3', 'p1.2', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'), 
('p1.3.1', 'p1.3', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'), 
('p2', 'Home', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'), 
('p2.1', 'p2', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'), 
('p2.2', 'p2.1', 'FALSE', 'false'),    
('P3', 'Home', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'), 
('p3.1', 'p3', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'), 
('P3.1.1', 'p3.1', 'FALSE', 'TRUE')
```

I tried

```
Select 
   b.Title,
   b.ParentTitle 
from 
   CTE B left join 
   CTE C ON C.ParentTitle=b.Title AND b.visible='TRue' 
where 
   b.ParentTitle in (Select a.ParentTitle 
                     from CTE A join CTE B on a.Title=b.ParentTitle and b.visible='false' )
```

I need output like

```
title
p1
p1.1
p2
p2.1
p2.2
P3
p3.1
```

need without recursive. using..joins..

Comment: Well You know parent level?

Comment: Yes..6 level...@NEER

Comment: any..one..solve..this...